# Aplicacion con GoogleMaps API solo funciona en el equipo de desarrollo

Tags: .net, geocodificación

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en .NET (C#) y SQL para delivery, y necesito calcular latitud y longitud de los domicilios de los clientes.

Estoy usando el Nuget Gmap.Net.Windows. En la computadora donde desarrollo anda sin problema.

Genere la API, y mediante un video de un Hindú (Dios los bendiga) logre lo que necesitaba.

El problema es cuando llevo el exe a otro equipo. Copio toda la carpeta DEBUG, con todas las DLL, instalo el Runtime de .NET Core y (Por lo que creo) no me toma la API, porque me devuelve error al usar la clase de reverse geocoding (Repito, siendo que en la computadora de desarrollo anda sin problemas)

Alguno puede decirme cual podria ser el problema? Cree otra API y pasa lo mismo, las dos APIS andan en la PC de desarrollo pero no en otro equipo

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpen, habia copiado todo el texto en Word y cuando pegue no puse "Buenas tardes"

Comment: si consideras que los hindues son buenos programando... que dios te bendiga a ti

Comment: siendo video de un hindu te diria que buscaras por variables globables... ejem, ejem... pero has probado a hacer un debugging en un ordenador distinto? que error te da? se te ha ocurrido pensar que igual el problema es que usas localizaciones absolutas (paths) y no relativos?

Comment: @Iria la verdad no se si son buenos o no, pero busque mucho y es el unico que mostraba desde 0 el desarrollo de algo que necesitaba hacer.

Con respecto a las localizaciones absolutas o relativas, ya desarrolle una aplicacion que esta instalada en muchos clientes y no he tenido problemas con las DLL (Estan todas en la carpeta raiz donde esta el ejecutable del sistema)

No tira error de ningun tipo, simplemente el statusCode devuelve rechazado.

Las clases me las toma sin problemas, lo que me da indicio de que las dll estarian bien instaladas

Comment: tiene pinta de que es una variable que te falla, puedes loggear todo lo que haces para el debugging y ver por donde te falla?

Comment: No sabria donde se hace eso jaja, lo mio es bastante rústico

Para mi, de faltarme una variable no compilaria en el equipo de desarrollo

Comment: No digo que te falte, sino que falle porque no actualizas su valor